# fadeIn and fadeOut in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write my own animations using JavaScript.

I wrote a function for `fadeIn()` as below, it changes the display property followed by a change in value of opacity. But it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function fadeIn(obj, defDisp) {
    obj.style.opacity = 0;
    obj.style.display = defDisp;
    var opVal = 0;
    while (opVal < 1) {
        obj.style.opacity = opVal;
        opVal += 0.1;
    }
}
```

`defDisp` = Default value for display property

Comment: A `while` loop executes almost instantly _(well, in that case)_. You won't see the animation this way. You need a recursive `setTimout` or a `setInterval` to add some delay between the different frames you want to show.

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working. How does it behave differently than expected? A live demo on JSBin would be nice, too.

Comment: you should likely use CSS transitions for the main part instead of JS, which can slow the page's interaction smoothness  and tends to look "jittery" compared to CSS animation.

Comment: you can reset the _display_ style back to _inherit_ instead of memorizing the old style.

Answer (score 1):

Without a timing interval, this will likely execute too fast for you to see it. The while loop, without a timeout feature, will execute in far less than a second, and you won't see it happen. It's like asking a computer to count to 10, it will do it in less than a millisecond.

Try using a setTimeout

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
while(opVal < 1) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        obj.style.opacity = opVal;
        opVal += 0.1;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Alter the timer (3000 in this case) to something that makes your fade work for you. Every 1000 is a one second and your loop runs 10 times, so in this case it would be 30 seconds, likely too slow.

I would probably stick with a CSS transition however, as they tend to render better on all browsers.

Comment: maybe like jquery set it to about 400ms by default

Comment: @dandavis The delayed functions are executed immediately after each other, there's only a 3 sec delay before the animation starts.

Comment: @Teemu: ahh, but then the delay between frames is zero... likely needs to add a number to 3000 to fix...

Comment: Teemu is correct, this is a rough example, you could start it off by firing off one event before starting on the rest, before the while loop starts.

Comment: this method is flawed because it does not introduce any delayed between each iteration of the loop. It will simply set up 10 setTimeout that will get fired in an instant 3000ms later

Comment: instead of using while loop use `setTimeout` recursively or use `setInterval` untill `opacity=1`

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that calls itself after a delay.

```js
function fadeIn(obj, defDisp) {
    obj.style.opacity = 0;
    obj.style.display = defDisp;
    var last = +new Date(); // Keep track of the time to calculate the opacity
    var fadeStep = function () {
        obj.style.opacity = +obj.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 800;
        last = +new Date();

        if (+obj.style.opacity < 1) {
            setTimeout(fadeStep, 16);
        }
    };
    fadeStep();
}


var el = document.getElementById('box');

fadeIn(el, 'block');
```

```css
#box{ padding: 1em; background: #009afd; color: #ffffff; display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="box">Hello</div>
```

If you want the fade to be faster, replace `800` by anything lower and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('fadein');

fadeIn(el);

function fadeIn(ele, defDisp) {
    
                ele.style.opacity = 0;
                ele.style.display = defDisp;
                var opVal = 0;
    
                var t = setInterval(function(){
                    if(opVal >= 1){
                      clearInterval(t);
                    }
                    ele.style.opacity = opVal;
                    opVal += 0.1;
                }, 100);
}
```

```css
#fadein{ background: #ccc; border:1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px }
```

```html
<div id="fadein">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because html render and for loop use the same thread, so when you doing the for-loop,you can't see any changes until the function complete. You have to use a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` (or `requestAnimationFrame` which is introduced from html5) so you browser can have the control to change the properties on the page:

You can see a example from the snippet, although the second that use a `setTimeout` is faster than the first one, which use `for loop`, the first one will not change its color as browser not able to change color during `for-loop`.

And if you choose to use `requestAnimationFrame` like I do in the snippets, you can have a smooth animation while the time can also be controlled precisely.

```js
function fadeIn() {
    this.style.opacity = 0;
    this.style.display = 'block';
    var opVal = 0;
    console.time("count");
    while(opVal < 1) {
        this.style.opacity = opVal;
        opVal += 0.000001;
    }
    console.timeEnd("count");
}

// Accept target as the target to apply anim, time is total anim time in ms.
function fadeInAlt(target, time) {
    var opacity = 0;
    var last = window.performance.now();
    console.time("count2");
    target.style.opacity = opacity;
    target.style.display = 'block';
    var fadeInFunc = function(timeStamp) {
        if (opacity < 1) {
            // Define the change by passed time.
            var timePassed = timeStamp - last;
            opacity += timePassed / time;
            target.style.opacity = opacity;
            last = timeStamp;
            requestAnimationFrame(fadeInFunc);
        } else {
          console.timeEnd("count2");
          return;
        }
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(fadeInFunc);
}

var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.onclick = fadeIn;

var div2 = document.getElementById('test2');
div2.onclick = function() {
  fadeInAlt(this, 3000);
};
```

```css
#test {
    background-color: red;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
}

#test2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```